# How to use Django annotate?

Tags: django, django-models

I'd like to ask, how I could shrink this to one command? I understand that *annotate* is proper way to do this,but don't understand how.

Here is my code, which is too slow:

```
sum = 0
for contact in self.contacts.all():
   sum += (contact.orders.aggregate(models.Sum('total'))['total__sum'])
return sum
```

I'd like to get *Sum* for each contact, all records in total column of relevant orders.

Code above produces sum, but is sluggishly slow. It is my understand it can be done with annotate,but not sure how to use it.

Here is Contact:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(
        Company, related_name="contacts", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField()
```

And here is Orders:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    order_number = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, related_name="orders")
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact, related_name="orders")
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=6)
    order_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Help please

Comment: Can you share the relevant parts of the `Contract` and `Order` model?

Comment: done, some irrelevant too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can annotate your queryset on the `Contract` model with:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

Contract.objects.annotate(
    total_orders=Sum('orders__total')
)
```

The `Contract` objects that arise from *this* queryset will have an extra attribute `.total_orders` that contains the sum of the `total` field of the *related* `Order` objects.

This will thus create a query that looks like:

```
SELECT contract.*, SUM(order.total)
FROM contract
LEFT OUTER JOIN order ON order.contract_id = contract.id
GROUP BY contract.id
```